# "Cannot Find Initializer" when using Objective-C class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

First time creating a swift app and it was going well until I ran into an issue when trying to use an Objective-C class into the Swift ViewController.

Objective-C Class Init (RKDropdownAlert.h)

```
+(void)title:(NSString*)title message:(NSString*)message backgroundColor:(UIColor*)backgroundColor textColor:(UIColor*)textColor time:(NSInteger)seconds;
```

My attempt:

```
var alert: RKDropdownAlert = RKDropdownAlert(title:"Error", message:"Please enter valid credentials.", backgroundColor:UIColor.redColor(), textColor:UIColor.whiteColor(), time:3)
```

Error: Cannot Find Initializer

How I've previously used the class in Objective C:

```
[RKDropdownAlert title:@"Error: Invalid Characters!" message:@"Please remove special characters from the field." backgroundColor:[UIColor redColor] textColor:[UIColor whiteColor] time:3];
```

I've been looking at this for over a hour now. Can anyone lend a hand? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is a class method and not an initializer, you have to call it with

```
RKDropdownAlert.title(title:NSString, message:NSString, ...)
```

if you want to make the method an initializer, you have to change the method declaration in the Objective-C file to

```
-(instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString*)title message:(NSString*)message backgroundColor:(UIColor*)backgroundColor textColor:(UIColor*)textColor time:(NSInteger)seconds;
```

and in the implementation:

```
-(instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString*)title message:(NSString*)message backgroundColor:(UIColor*)backgroundColor textColor:(UIColor*)textColor time:(NSInteger)seconds
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        //Create your alert here
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Class method should be fine, as long as the name follows the right pattern, i.e. `+alertWithTitle:message:...`